# Query for rows including child rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-express

A few weeks ago, I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409228/generate-structured-xml-document-from-hierarchical-table-data-t-sql) about how to generate hierarchical XML from a table, that has a parentID column.
It all works fine. The point is, according to the hierarchy, I also want to query a table.

I'll give you an example:

Thats the table with the codes:

```
ID          CODE         NAME                                               PARENTID
1           ROOT         IndustryCode                                       NULL
2           IND          Industry                                           1
3           CON          Consulting                                         1
4           FIN          Finance                                            1
5           PHARM        Pharmaceuticals                                    2
6           AUTO         Automotive                                         2
7           STRAT        Strategy                                           3
8           IMPL         Implementation                                     3
9           CFIN         Corporate Finance                                  4
10          CMRKT        Capital Markets                                    9
```

From which I generate (for displaying in a TreeViewControl) this XML:

```
<record key="1" parentkey="" Code="ROOT" Name="IndustryCode">
  <record key="2" parentkey="1" Code="IND" Name="Industry">
    <record key="5" parentkey="2" Code="PHARM" Name="Pharmaceuticals" /> 
    <record key="6" parentkey="2" Code="AUTO" Name="Automotive" /> 
  </record>
  <record key="3" parentkey="1" Code="CON" Name="Consulting">
    <record key="7" parentkey="3" Code="STRAT" Name="Strategy" /> 
    <record key="8" parentkey="3" Code="IMPL" Name="Implementation" /> 
  </record>
  <record key="4" parentkey="1" Code="FIN" Name="Finance">
    <record key="9" parentkey="4" Code="CFIN" Name="Corporate Finance">
      <record key="10" parentkey="9" Code="CMRKT" Name="Capital Markets" /> 
    </record>
  </record>
</record>
```

As you can see, some codes are subordinate to others, for example AUTO << IND << ROOT

What I want (and have absolutely no idea how to realise or even, where to start) is to be able to **query another table** (where one column is this certain code of course) **for a code and get all records with the specific code and all subordinate codes**

For example: I query the other table for "IndustryCode = IND[ustry]" and get (of course) the records containing "IND", *but also* AUTO[motive] and PHARM[aceutical] (= all subordinates)

Its an SQL Express Server 2008 with Advanced Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I usually do this is by adding a `keychain` column. For your data:

```
ID          PARENTID       KEYCHAIN
1           NULL           1
2           1              1.2
3           1              1.3
4           1              1.4
5           2              1.2.5
6           2              1.2.6
7           3              1.3.7
8           3              1.3.8
9           4              1.4.9
10          9              1.4.9.10
```

This column would obviously have to be calculated at insert using the generated id, but once it's in there you can write your query quite simply.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE KEYCHAIN like '1.2.%' or KEYCHAIN = '1.2'
```

There are probably other ways to do this, but I've found this method to work pretty well.

Comment: You can also use nested sets method, but Keychain looks simplier and needs only one additional field to be filled

Comment: how would you calculate the keychain? There has to be some kinda recursion I guess?

Comment: @MAD9, Yes it would be form of recursion. For one row, though you could write `UPDATE mytable t1 SET KEYCHAIN = (SELECT KEYCHAIN FROM mytable t2 WHERE t1.PARENTID = t2.ID) + '.' + ID`

Comment: As a side note, have a look at hierachyid support in SQL2008. It builds the chain for you automagically.

Comment: @CResults, I remember some talk about that when 2008 first came out, but I've never used it. Next time I need to design a hierarchical table, I'll definitely look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
WITH hierarchy AS (
   SELECT x.code
     FROM TABLE x
    WHERE x.code = @root_code
   UNION ALL
   SELECT y.code
     FROM TABLE y
     JOIN hierarchy h ON h.id = y.parentid)
SELECT z.code
  FROM hierarchy z
```

It's a typical (now ANSI standard) [hierarchical query](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927200924/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml) - there's lots to be found on google about them.