# construct xml for unknow depth

Tags: xml, t-sql

I have a column with values like:

```
/root,
/root/first,
/root/first/one,
```

I don't know the depth of the xml path. I need to construct a xml like

```
<root>
    <first>
        <one></one>
    </first>
</root>
```

Any tsql help to group all child elements to their parents will be helpful
thank you

Comment: My first thought is recursive CTE but you might look this over: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409228/generate-structured-xml-document-from-hierarchical-table-data-t-sql

Comment: Can you share what you've tried thus far? And is this for SQL Server or a different product?

Comment: is there a reason you have to do this in tsql instead of outside the database? seems like it would be more trivial to do in C#/ruby/php/etc.

Comment: I'm wondering about the meaning of this data because if affects what kind of solution you might want. For example, is there anything preventing you from having duplicates, and if not what would the duplicates mean? Because if you had two `/root/first` entries, then what would your desired XML look like?

Comment: And come to think of eat, **each row** in your example data would represent a full XML tree by itself (`<root></root>` for the first row, `<root><first></first></root>` for the second, and so forth). I set up [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8b9b/10) to show how you can get the XML document for any given row, but I can't go much further until I know more about your data.